# grunt-browserify alias stop working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, watchify

I have simple grunt-browserify config. This configuration works perfectly until I change any JavaScript file, then "watchify" compiles build again. Since that moment build.js fails in browser with exception: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'i18n'`

Seems like "watchify" ingnores alias option, or Am I doing something wrong ?

```
browserify: {
    client: {
        src: ['app/app.js'],
        dest: 'app/build.js',
        options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
                debug: true
            },
            alias: [
                './app/dispatchers/appDispatcher.js:appDispatcher',
                './app/models/i18n.js:i18n'
            ],
            watch: true
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Update. If change is in app.js file then build.js works without exceptions. However if I change any other *.js file within project then build.js fails.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `cache:false` solves the problem. My only concern is that caching helps to speed up the process. So but turning it off I'm slowing down re-building process.

```
        ...
        browserifyOptions: {
            ...
            cache: false
        }
        ...
```

Problem comes from "module-deps" package. Following commit fixes this issue. Wait for official build and then caching option can be removed.
[link to commit](https://github.com/zertosh/module-deps/commit/9080ba995043708a35601dc49d2a719e77d08929)